# Is "what did he say" pronounced /wɒ ti di seɪ/ for contraction in everyday quick speak?

Tags: pronunciation

I know there are rules for pronunciation contraction and I learned some of those, I still not sure about this one

> "What did he say?"

Is it pronounced /wɒ ti di seɪ/ for contraction in everyday quick speak?

Comment: Yes, it sounds something like this: *What didi say?* The "he" is reduced to a single "e" sound.

Comment: @MichaelRybkin Thank you. Would you please introduce some relevant rules (terms, names or links, etc) for this kind of situations?

Comment: I'm not aware of any kinds of rules for that. However, there are entire YouTube channels dedicated specifically to this aspect of English, that is, pronunciation.

Comment: In rapid colloquial speech you may hear it further reduced to /wɒ di seɪ/.